# Pay calculator invalid syntax

Tags: python

simple thing. Syntax error near unexpected token `('

```
Hours = int(input('How many hours did you work this week?'))
Rate = int(input('What is your hourly rate?'))
Pay = Hours + Rate
print(Pay)
```

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: Does this error only happen when you run the code from your IDE? What happens if you run it from the command line?

Comment: That was the output I got from the terminal. When I run it in Atom I don't get any output. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: And yes that's all. It's my first attempt to make something in Atom

Comment: As the code sits you don't have any syntactical errors. Did you paste it exactly as you have it in the IDE? [Your code runs](https://repl.it/repls/NotedPlayfulGeeklog)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse yes

Comment: Running python3 if it matters

Comment: @JohnDoe Scroll up and down, make sure you don't have anything else. See the link in my comment above. Your code works.  It would be helpful to post the full error traceback in this case.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code using Python? Because https://appuals.com/fix-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token/ indicates that `Syntax error near unexpected token `('` typically appears when you enter a malformed command directly into a command prompt. You're not just pasting your code straight into the terminal, are you?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `Hours * Rate`?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I see. I really don't know what I'm doing. I cd into the directory the file is and run with.     . /filename. Py

Comment: @JohnDoe Run if via `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py` depending on your OS. (or add a shebang).

Comment: @Kevin no I'm trying to run a   . Py file

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse thank you. That's what I was doing wrong. I feel dumb but I gotta figure it out somehow haha.